# How to install Ubuntu alongside encrypted Windows 7?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows, wubi, encryption

I have Windows 7 booted via BIOS(not UEFI) and encrypted by PGP. I would like to have a dual boot installation of Ubuntu on external USB hard-drive. Installation Wizard of Ubuntu does not offer an Alongside option. My guess is it does not see current Windows, since the disk is encrypted.

My booting sequence is - 1st power-on/hdd password(set in BIOS). Then there is an option to boot from another device, then comes PGP screen where I enter the password. Then actually comes Dual boot screen added by Wubi.

Can it be done? How?

Comment: I don't want to perform a risky operation during which I might corrupt my current Windows installation irreparably. But I have no "moral problem" with using system image recovery.

Comment: The closest thing that i could think of is creating a seperate `/boot` partition for handling encryption and bootloader

Comment: I myself haven't ventured in that field too much but i found something over intenet that might help you http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14227/multi-boot-with-full-hard-drive-encryption-and-pre-boot-authentication

Comment: Thank you. Oh my, this looks much more complicated as what I was hoping for(hoped it would get cured by some checkbox in a wizard :D)

Comment: Haha, we could only hope, goodluck ;)

Comment: Isn't there a chance to avoid problems with bootloaders by manually selecting from what drive it should be booted up? I mean the BIOS feature which normally can be used to boot Live USB. I dont need to have the external drive encrypted, I don't need to access my windows drive from external OS.

Comment: Yes that could be possible, it will be just like putting your boot partition on usb storage to make it starter for os.

Comment: OK, what I am planning to do then is following:
1. physically remove my hdd, just to be sure it wont get messed up  
2. boot live usb ubuntu
3. run the installation to another usb storage
4. report my results here

Comment: Ok, Keep us updated on your progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **Yes**.

- Create Live USB Storage
- Boot it
- Install to USB Storage#2
- Boot from USB Storage#2

For safety, remove primary HDD before installing(for paranoiacs mainly)

Comment: **Downfall**

My main motivation was to be able to have the media files on USB Storage#2 accessible in Windows and on my Smart TV. This is actually impossible to do properly(at least to my knowledge). I installed to a 'Removable drive', it's just a type defined by one Bit on the device. Some manufacturers provide a tool to switch this byte to 'Fixed drive'. I can't. Windows does not allow Removables to be multipartitioned.

Comment: Ive tried a [workaround][1] - Windows could play along if you set the Windows readable partition to be first in order. This actually worked, I could finally mount the partition in Windows. After soft restart I could boot from USB. But after turning off&on the PC, my BIOS refused to detect the storage. I had to boot to windows, reattach the storage and then it got detected by windows and after soft restart(restart executed in Windows/not HW reset - BIOS password is remembered) I could boot from USB storage again.

  [1]: http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/multipartufd "workaround"

Comment: Installing to FAT32 is not possible for Ubuntu, nor Linux Mint, despite the misleading info I found. Mint has actually totally identical installation wizard as Ubuntu